# Covert pandas data frame to numpy array, inserting np.nan when necessary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to convert a pandas data frame to a numpy array. I usually use `df.to_numpy()`, which allows to specify data type (`float` or `int` in my case). However some of the values are not numbers, and I would like to coerce them to `np.nan`. I cannot use a simple replacement rule, since the not number values are given by different symbols, which I do not know in advance. (It is basically about cleaning a dataset).

Answer (score 1):

You can first [convert to numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `'coerce'`. This will set anything that can't be converted to `np.nan`.

```
pd.to_numeric(pd.Series([1,'a', '1.1.2', 1.1]),'coerce').to_numpy()
#array([1. , nan, nan, 1.1])
```